# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i! \overset{12}\equiv 9\;\forall n \geq 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i! \overset{12}\equiv 9\;\forall n \geq 4$$

I'm trying to use induction, but I can't manage to solve this problem. Here's what I did so far:

**Base case** $n=4\implies 1+2+3!+4!\overset{12}\equiv33\overset{12}\equiv9$

**Induction hypotesis** $\sum_{i=1}^{k}i! \overset{12}\equiv9$ for some $k\geq 4$

**Induction step** $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i!\overset{12}\equiv (k+1)!+\sum_{i=1}^{k}i!\overset{12}\equiv (k+1)!+9$$

But that's about it, I don't really know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $n \geq 4$, $n! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots n = 24 \cdot 5 \cdots n = 0 \mod 12$, you don't even need induction

Comment: You could incorporate that into the induction proof if you must.

Comment: Perhaps you could type that comment up as an answer, @JulesBesson.

Comment: If you wish :)!

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a more compact notation for $a\equiv b(\mod m)$ (whose kerning annoys me if I use `\mod` instead of e.g. `\operatorname{mod}` which looks like $a\equiv b(\operatorname{mod}m)$), namely $a\overset{m}{\equiv}b$ (although I'd usually use `\stackrel` instead of `\overset`, for no particular reason; it looks like $a\stackrel{m}{\equiv}b$).

Comment: @J.G. `\mod` is supposed to be used as $a\equiv b\mod m$. The correct version with parentheses is `\pmod`: $a\equiv b\pmod m$. There is also a `\pod`: $a\equiv b\pod m$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for that. Let me test it: $a\equiv b\pmod m$ (`a\equiv b\pmod m`). (Interestingly, it doesn't work in LyX.) Why "p", though?

Comment: p = parenthesized, I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I was saying in the comments, you don't need to use induction, but it will work for the same following reason.

Take $k \geq 4$,
$$k! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots k = 24 \cdot 5 \cdots k = 0 \mod 12.$$
This gives you
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i! = 1! + 2! + 3! + \sum_{i=4}^n i! = 9 + 0 \mod 12.$$

Here you go! If you still want to use induction, just use the first result.

Answer (score 0):

Notice,

$1!+2!+3!\equiv9$ (mod 12)

and

for $n>3$
We found, $12$|$n!$

Hence,
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i!= 1! + 2! + 3! + \sum_{i=4}^n i! \equiv9$  (mod 12),  for all $n>3$